# Does my wallet secured

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet

I have an aged notebook, and find there is an wallet on it.
[image: wallet]

Does this mean that this wallet is unsecured and I can transfer btn from it without passphrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the screenshot your wallet is not encrypted and does not need a password; HOWEVER since your node is still syncing, note where it says "3 years and 4 weeks behind", you cannot trust the balance. So wait for it to finish syncing. If you still have a balance after fully synced then your coins are still on that wallet and should be spendable.